# Mac: How to sync specific address book contacts with a business partner?

Tags: macos, sync, contacts, address-book, icloud

I have a mac and an iPhone. My friend has a mac and an iPhone. We both use those devices privately and for our shared business.

I wonder what's the best and easiest way to sync address book contacts with each other over the cloud. I thought of using Google Contacts to do so but I cant figure out how to only sync certain contacts.

E.g. imagine this. We have an "intelligent group" in our address book called "business" where all our business contacts are in. And we want to share this group with each other.

It would be best if it would sync completely wirelessly between our two accounts and phones. 
Imagine I save a new number and contact on my iphone (associated with my "business" group - I want my friend to have this contact on his phone as well.

Any suggestions? I guess this is not possible right now? Any app recommendations that do stuff like that?

Thank you in advance,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My boss and I do this for work.
We made a separate Gmail account and used Gmail's built-in mobile exchange server.
On our phones, we named the account "Work Syncing" so that whenever we add a contact to our phone, we manually go to that contact group and add them, as opposed to "On my iPhone" or "iCloud."

Also note: Google documentation says that to prevent gmail from syncing all your contacts, you have to say "Delete existing contacts."  I'm not sure about that.
When I did it, I already had iCloud syncing all of my contacts so when I added gmail exchange, it made a separate group called "Work Syncing."  Thus as a precaution, I would recommend syncing with iCloud first.  It will then take ownership of all the contacts on your phone, so Gmail will make a separate contact group.  Then you can enable in your settings whether you want new contacts to default to your iCloud or gmail account.

On the iPhones - [How to setup Google mobile exchange](http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740)
On the mac - [How to setup contact sync in Lion](http://www.gilsmethod.com/how-to-sync-google-contacts-with-mac-os-lion)

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a free solution? If not, I think I'd go with Full Contact--it's a cloud contact manager (vcard, social media, email) and the biz version lets you share certain lists with others in your organization. 
http://www.fullcontact.com/business/